# Compare field values in same row SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

**table structure**

```
id | name | date_usa | date_jpn | date_uk
---+------+----------+----------+--------
 1 |    a |  01/2015 |  12/2014 | 04/2015
 2 |    b |  05/2015 |  05/2015 | 05/2015
 3 |    c |  08/2016 |  09/2017 | 09/2017
```

I want it to list out:

```
earliest release dates:
a: 12/2014
b: 05/2015
c: 08/2016
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name, least(date_usa, date_jpn, date_uk)
from your_table
```